# Using Microsoft Sync framework, I would like have multiple clients adding records to specific table (MS SQL)

Tags: sql-server-2008, synchronization

I am using MS Sync Framework 2.1 to sync records on multiple clients and main server which works fantastic as long as all the records have the same primary key.

My problem now arises on a specific table that multiple clients use at once to insert different items in that specific table on the client machine. So when I want to do a sync I want to see all records of the different clients on the Server (not required but it will appear on the clients as well). There is a primary key available, but this type of scan adds new records. The order or PK is not important, just as long the data from the clients get added to the server table.

An example of what I want to do:
Before Sync:

```
Client 1:
PK | data
1  | one 
2  | two

Client 2:
PK | data
1  | three 
2  | four

Client 2:
PK | data
1  | Five 
2  | Six

Server
PK  | data
null| null
```

After Sync:

```
Client 1:
PK | data
1  | one 
2  | two 
3  | three (Not req'd)
4  | four (Not req'd)
5  | Five (Not req'd)
6  | Six (Not req'd)

Client 2:
PK | data
1  | one (Not req'd)
2  | two (Not req'd)
3  | three 
4  | four
5  | Five (Not req'd)
6  | Six (Not req'd)

Client 3:
PK | data 
1  | one  (Not req'd)
2  | two( Not req'd)
3  | three (Not req'd) 
4  | four (Not req'd)
5  | Five 
6  | Six

   Server
   PK  | data
    1  | one 
    2  | two
    3  | three 
    4  | four
    5  | Five 
    6  | Six
```

If any one can please explain to me how to do this I would appreciate it immensely

Answer (score 1):

You might need to consider setting primary key data type as a GUID. (SQL server uniqueidentifier) Please read the document from Microsoft below link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726011.aspx